# Pass event from overlayed div to Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I'm using Highmaps to show a simple map and over it I have another div with a component that draws things on top of the map (this has to be done this way, I cannot draw everything inside Highmaps, unfortunely).

Now I would like to have some interation with the map, although it is below my div. I would like to know if there is a way to trigger the click, hover, etc. events on the map when I click on the div on top of it.

I have searched [Highmaps docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/) trying to find a method a-like `trigger(ev, x, y)` but there seems to be none. Then I tried a pure javascript solution using [MouseEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) and `dispatchEvent()` on the Map DOM, but it also didn't work.

I have set up a simple fiddle with what I want to work: http://jsfiddle.net/k11yfz58/1/

If we coment the `#overlay` div, we get an alert when we click in a state. I want the same behavior but clicking on the overlay div, is that possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

It was suggested to use the `pointer-events` CSS property for this. That does not solve my problem because I also need the events to be triggered on the `#overlay` div.

Comment: Highcharts uses not only dom events but also custom events - those events can be dispatched by Highcharts.fireEvent or Point.prototype.firePointEvent - see the example https://jsfiddle.net/2u400kp9/. What you try to do - manually firing events - might be very hard to achieve. I think you should reconsider putting that overlay on the chart - drawing additional/custom items on the charts seems to be a much cleaner way to go.

Comment: Unfortunely drawing inside highmaps is not an option. The div on top of it actually holds another complex graphical component that uses canvas. For now I will work on a functionality to hide the div on top through a button when the user wants to interact with the map, but Im still open to ideas on how to achieve the desirable behavior of passing the events.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your css:

```
#overlay {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> The pointer-events CSS property specifies under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events.

and the `none` value:

> **none**
>   The element is never the target of mouse events; however, **mouse events may target its descendant elements** if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

What this means is that your overlay element is "invisible" to mouse events, and thus mouse events occur on the div below.

Comment: Hi Métoule, thanks for the answer. I did not know about this property but unfortunelly this does not solve my problem. I still need that the events also happen on the `#overlay` div as well... :/ 
Do you have any other idea?